# consulta a una relación reflexiva

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo la siguiente relacion y lo que busco es obtner todos los registros de los hijos con sus padres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo máximo que pude hacer es listar todos los hijos, pero tambien necesito el nombre de los padres

```
select personas.nombre from personas
inner join hijo_padre hijo on hijo.persona_hijo_id = personas.id;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debes hacer una consulta left join, por ejemplo con este esquema:

```
CREATE TABLE persona (
    id integer auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE padre_hijo (
    id integer auto_increment primary key,
    padre_id integer not null,
    hijo_id integer not null
);
INSERT INTO persona (name) VALUES 
('Juan'), ('Antonio'), ('Ana'), ('Lucia'), ('Andres'), ('Marta');

INSERT INTO padre_hijo (padre_id, hijo_id) VALUES
(1, 5), (3, 5), (2, 6), (4, 6);
```

Podriamos hacer la siguiente query

```
SELECT
    h.name as nombre_hijo,
    p.name as nombre_padre
FROM padre_hijo as cn 
LEFT JOIN persona as p on cn.padre_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN persona as h on cn.hijo_id = h.id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O esta para concatenar los nombres de todos los padres

```
SELECT
    h.name as nombre_hijo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.name, ' ') as padres
FROM padre_hijo as cn 
LEFT JOIN persona as p on cn.padre_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN persona as h on cn.hijo_id = h.id
GROUP BY h.id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta más simple sería:

```
SELECT 
    P.nombre 
FROM 
    personas P, 
    hijo_padre H 
WHERE 
    H.persona_hijo_id = P.id 
    and 
    H.persona_padre_id = P.id;
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Tienes razón, mi respuesta es demasiado vaga, solo que no sé que comentarios de funcionalidad agregarle a un select tan simple.

Comment: podrías poner el tipo de join que se usa, y si influye o no que sea una relación reflexiva por ejemplo